# Custom validation error don't work as expected

Tags: java, validation, jsf, jsf-2

I want to validate a field to be able to accept values only between 1 and 100. It works fine, but when i write a something that is not an integer is don't see the custom message i expect.

This is the field:

```
<h:inputText id="discountPercentage" value="#{newOfferSupportController.discountPercentage}" validator="#{newOfferSupportController.validateDiscountPercentage}"/>
            <span style="color: red;"><h:message for="discountPercentage"
                showDetail="true" /></span>
```

This is the validator method:

```
public void validateDiscountPercentage(FacesContext context,
            UIComponent validate, Object value) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("");
        String inputFromField = "" + value.toString();
        String simpleTextPatternText = "^([1-9]|[1-9]\\d|100)$";
        Pattern textPattern = null;
        Matcher productValueMatcher = null;
        textPattern = Pattern.compile(simpleTextPatternText);
        productValueMatcher = textPattern.matcher(inputFromField);

        if (!productValueMatcher.matches()) {
            msg = new FacesMessage("Only values between 1 and 100 allowed");
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < inputFromField.length(); i++) {
            // If we find a non-digit character throw Exception
            if (!Character.isDigit(inputFromField.charAt(i))) {
                msg = new FacesMessage("Only numbers allowed");
                throw new ValidatorException(msg);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the error i message i see when i ester something that is not a number:

[image]

Why i don't see the message: Only numbers allowed?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but isn't this  field productValue and not  discountPercentage ?

Comment: Yes you are right there is another field called productValue with the same issue, i just print screened the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use jsf's [`LongRangeValidator`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnatf/index.html) for this purpose?

```
<h:inputText id="discountPercentage" 
      value="#{newOfferSupportController.discountPercentage}">
   <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="100"/>
</h:inputText>
```

You can even define your own custom validation messages if the default messages don't fit your needs. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766049/localized-jsf-default-validators/4766078#4766078) for more information.

Besides this, your error message is for `productValue` and not for `discountPercentage`.