# Primefaces password feedback text localization

Tags: primefaces

I'm having a problem translating the ff text from primefaces's password field:
"Please enter a password", "Weak", "Good", "Strong", etc.

Any idea how to override the default translation values? I tried searching the primefaces jar but can't see them in Messages.properties file.

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the the showcase:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/password.jsf

Here is the turkish example copied from there:

```
<p:password id="turkishFeedback" value="#{passwordBean.password3}" feedback="true"   
    promptLabel="Lütfen şifre giriniz" 
    weakLabel="Zayıf"  
    goodLabel="Orta seviye" 
    strongLabel="Güçlü" />
```

Comment: Hi Aksel, thanks for the reply. Yes I've already seen those attributes, but what I'm looking for is like the jsf contants: javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM. Sorry if I did not made it clear with the post.

Comment: you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766049/localized-jsf-default-validators

Comment: Yes, just like that but I can't find the key.

Comment: they are part of jsf api. here is another example how to find and replace them: www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/